# Get method in golang

Tags: http, go

I have to do a job for the university and the truth is that I cannot carry it out, I need to request data from an API through GET, the issue is that the API asks me to be logged in to consume said data, how can I perform this authentication from GO ?, please help :(

```
clienteHttp := &http.Client{}
url := "https://web.copiloto.ai/api/rawdata?vehicles=238&from=2021-05-20T00:00:00&to=2021-05-20T23:59:59&fields=$basic,ecu_bms1_total_voltage&distance=km"
peticion, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error creando petición: %v", err)

}

peticion.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
peticion.Header.Add("X-Hola-Mundo", "Ejemplo")
respuesta, err := clienteHttp.Do(peticion)
if err != nil {
    
    log.Fatalf("Error haciendo petición: %v", err)
}

defer respuesta.Body.Close()

cuerpoRespuesta, err := ioutil.ReadAll(respuesta.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error leyendo respuesta: %v", err)
}

respuestaString := string(cuerpoRespuesta)
log.Printf("Código de respuesta: %d", respuesta.StatusCode)
log.Printf("Encabezados: '%q'", respuesta.Header)
contentType := respuesta.Header.Get("Content-Type")
log.Printf("El tipo de contenido: '%s'", contentType)
log.Printf("Cuerpo de respuesta del servidor: '%s'", respuestaString)
```

resp :

```
2021/05/25 18:12:26 Cuerpo de respuesta del servidor: '{"message": "User is NOT Logged in | Authenticated"}
```

At the moment I only know that to consume data from the browser I must be logged into the page, in this way I can obtain the data, but nothing outside the browser

**upgrade: To log in I have to send the username and password through the POST method, I have the username and password, what should I do?
when testing in postman I receive the following**

```
{
"message": "User successfully authenticated",
"app": null,
"auth": "4fe0e1733199bdaf1f7106aeea7754e6389ef1b7fa19e24a4"}
```

Comment: Could you supply the API link or at least specify what kind of authentication they require you to use? Is it basic auth / some sort of token / something else?

Comment: I went to the website, but it requires you to authenticate first. Could you maybe send the API documentation?

Comment: @ViktorRozenko I already have the user name and password, in postman it works fine, how can I implement this in GO?

Answer (score 1):

With a user name and password, you might be able to make use of HTTP Basic Auth.

```
peticion.SetBasicAuth("user1", "passwd1!")
```

The thing to remember with Basic Auth is that your credentials are not encrypted.  And if you add them to your code, they will be there for future developers to see.  If you need to protect them, you will need to make the inputs to the program or something like that so that they are not just sitting in code.

For reference: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.SetBasicAuth